# Security Vulnerability XSS Dom based

Tags: security, dom, xss, zap

We are using the ZAP tool for our application security testing and running across a High priority vulnerability in form of Cross site XSS DOM based. Attached image for reference.

Can someone help to set a direction to resolve this. What could be the possible areas we can look into

Additional information : We are using the following libraries in our application JQuery 3.6.0, Bootstrap 4.3.1 [Screen Shot ZAP report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3OLq.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the current solution associated with that [alert](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/alerts/40026/):

```
Phase: Architecture and Design Use a vetted library or framework that does not
allow this weakness to occur or provides constructs that make this weakness
easier to avoid. Examples of libraries and frameworks that make it easier to
generate properly encoded output include Microsoft's Anti-XSS library, the OWASP
ESAPI Encoding module, and Apache Wicket. Phases: Implementation; Architecture
and Design Understand the context in which your data will be used and the
encoding that will be expected. This is especially important when transmitting
data between different components, or when generating outputs that can contain
multiple encodings at the same time, such as web pages or multi-part mail
messages. Study all expected communication protocols and data representations to
determine the required encoding strategies. For any data that will be output to
another web page, especially any data that was received from external inputs,
use the appropriate encoding on all non-alphanumeric characters. Consult the XSS
Prevention Cheat Sheet for more details on the types of encoding and escaping
that are needed. Phase: Architecture and Design For any security checks that are
performed on the client side, ensure that these checks are duplicated on the
server side, in order to avoid CWE-602. Attackers can bypass the client-side
checks by modifying values after the checks have been performed, or by changing
the client to remove the client-side checks entirely. Then, these modified
values would be submitted to the server. If available, use structured mechanisms
that automatically enforce the separation between data and code. These
mechanisms may be able to provide the relevant quoting, encoding, and validation
automatically, instead of relying on the developer to provide this capability at
every point where output is generated. Phase: Implementation For every web page
that is generated, use and specify a character encoding such as ISO-8859-1 or
UTF-8. When an encoding is not specified, the web browser may choose a different
encoding by guessing which encoding is actually being used by the web page. This
can cause the web browser to treat certain sequences as special, opening up the
client to subtle XSS attacks. See CWE-116 for more mitigations related to
encoding/escaping. To help mitigate XSS attacks against the user's session
cookie, set the session cookie to be HttpOnly. In browsers that support the
HttpOnly feature (such as more recent versions of Internet Explorer and
Firefox), this attribute can prevent the user's session cookie from being
accessible to malicious client-side scripts that use document.cookie. This is
not a complete solution, since HttpOnly is not supported by all browsers. More
importantly, XMLHTTPRequest and other powerful browser technologies provide read
access to HTTP headers, including the Set-Cookie header in which the HttpOnly
flag is set. Assume all input is malicious. Use an 'accept known good' input
validation strategy, i.e., use an allow list of acceptable inputs that strictly
conform to specifications. Reject any input that does not strictly conform to
specifications, or transform it into something that does. Do not rely
exclusively on looking for malicious or malformed inputs (i.e., do not rely on a
deny list). However, deny lists can be useful for detecting potential attacks or
determining which inputs are so malformed that they should be rejected outright.
When performing input validation, consider all potentially relevant properties,
including length, type of input, the full range of acceptable values, missing or
extra inputs, syntax, consistency across related fields, and conformance to
business rules. As an example of business rule logic, 'boat' may be
syntactically valid because it only contains alphanumeric characters, but it is
not valid if you are expecting colors such as 'red' or 'blue.' Ensure that you
perform input validation at well-defined interfaces within the application. This
will help protect the application even if a component is reused or moved
elsewhere.
```

It's quite a wall of text, it wasn't written by me :)

You should also refer to the DOM XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html which outlines 7 rules:

- RULE #1 - HTML Escape then JavaScript Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML Subcontext within the Execution Context
- RULE #2 - JavaScript Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML Attribute Subcontext within the Execution Context
- RULE #3 - Be Careful when Inserting Untrusted Data into the Event Handler and JavaScript code Subcontexts within an Execution Context
- RULE #4 - JavaScript Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into the CSS Attribute Subcontext within the Execution Context
- RULE #5 - URL Escape then JavaScript Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into URL Attribute Subcontext within the Execution Context
- RULE #6 - Populate the DOM using safe JavaScript functions or properties
- RULE #7 - Fixing DOM Cross-site Scripting Vulnerabilities

  - Which further defines 12 guidelines.

Comment: Thank you @kingthorin for your response. We will go through, apply and let you know if we have any further queries.